# Required and Optional Field in Django Formset

Tags: python, django, forms, formset

I created a formset to replicate over two input fields, first name and last name.  I wanted to make the first set of "first name" and "last name" field to be required while the second, and third set as optional.  In another word, at least one of the three set input box must be filled out.  Is there a way to do this?  Do I have to make 2 separate form/formset to accommodate this?

The reason for my question is I wanted to have 3 sets of first name and last name field.  If a user only fill out one of the 3 sets and click Submit, Django will throw a **Key Error** because the other 2 sets aren't filled in.

forms.py

```
from django import forms


class NameForm (forms.Form):

    first_name = forms.CharField (max_length = 20, required = False)
    last_name = forms.CharField (max_length = 20, required = False)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
from nameform.forms import NameForm
from nameform.addName import webform


# Create your views here.
def addname (request):
    NameFormSet = formset_factory (NameForm, extra = 2, max_num = 5)    # Set maximum to avoid default of 1000 forms.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Django will become valid even if an empty form is submitted. Adding initial data causes unbound form and
        # trigger formset.errors
        formset = NameFormSet (request.POST, initial = [{'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Doe'}])

        if formset.is_valid ():
            location = request.POST ['site']
            data = formset.cleaned_data

            for form in data:
                firstname = form ['first_name']
                lastname = form ['last_name']

                webform (firstname, lastname, location)

            context = {'data': data, 'location': location}

            return render (request, 'nameform/success.html', context)

    else:
        formset = NameFormSet ()

    return render (request, 'nameform/addname.html', {'formset': formset})
```

Here are the steps that I've tried:

1. If I removed the "required = False", it would make every form in the formset required.  KeyError will be flagged if the user only filled out the first set and leave the second set blank.
2. Making this formset as optional like above will also throw a KeyError if user submitted a blank form.

[image: Add Name Form]

[image: KeyError - firstname = form ['first_name']

Answer (score 1):

Django formset in this case works in a peculiar way - forms without data have empty `cleaned_data` but treated as valid.  So you have to manually check existence of form data:

```
# at imports section of views.py
from django.forms.util import ErrorList

# at addname()
actual_data = []
for form in data:
    firstname = form.get('first_name')
    lastname = form.get('last_name')
    if firstname and lastname:
        webform (firstname, lastname, location)
        actual_data.append(form)
if actual_data:
    context = {'data': actual_data, 'location': location}
    return render(request, 'nameform/success.html', context)
formset._non_form_errors = ErrorList(['Enter at least one person name.'])
```

Comment: Your method eliminate the error; however, my success page now only show the location for the 2 fields.  First name & last name is missing.  Secondly, my webform method return the print result of first name and last name.  In this case, I don't see it printed in the terminal.  What's the difference between accessing the dictionary by form ['first_name'] versus your method form.get ('first_name')?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: I removed the initial data and made the changes suggested, the form went through.  However, now a user can just submit a blank form which brought us back to this same question.

Comment: `dict[key]` throws `KeyError` exception of case if there is no such key in `dict`. `dict.get(key)` in this case just returns `None` without any exception.

Comment: I edited my answer to resolve your problem.  And don't forget to output `{{ formset.non_form_errors }}` in your template.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanation.  I realized that after reading up on dictionary KeyError.  Your method worked when there's no input but if I just entered only the first name or last name it didn't give me a "non_form_errors.  One method that I found worked is to set the html input field required for both first name and last name field but it's not djangonic nor pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

you need to inherit from BaseFormSet and override "clean" method to implement manual validation .

the django docs has an example : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/#custom-formset-validation